# How to set up Laravel cron job in Bluehost

Tags: cron, queue, laravel-5.4, bluehost

I have hosted a Laravel project in bluehost. Since it is a shared hosting i can not get to work Laravel queue. Therefore need to run cron job for that.

I tried to run this command in cron job

```
php /home1/ja22/public_html/exam/artisan schedule:run 1>> /dev/null 2>&1
```

/// backend code ////

```
home1/ja22/exam-backend
```

// public folder ////

```
home1/ja22/public_html/exam
```

but it doesn't work. So it should be problem with the `cron path` i setup.Please help to setup the path correctly

Answer (score 1):

I got it working

```
/usr/bin/php /home1/ja22/exam-backend/artisan schedule:run 1>> /dev/null 2>&1
```

Answer (score 0):

It's just simple:

```
php /path/to/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

For me the path to artisan was: *public_html/dev/core/artisan*
Hence it's:

```
php public_html/dev/core/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```